# Django UKPhoneNumberField problem!

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm currently using [UKPhoneNumberField](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1207/) in one of my forms. I recently found that if I submit a London number `02081112222` (or as `020 8111 2222`) it saves the number as `020 81112222 8111` in the DB. I'm not very good at debugging python so I was wondering if someone could help me track down the problem. Cheers

**EDIT:**

I sure it is something to do with the `format_number` function since I commented it out my problems go away *(yes, I know it's not a solution, just a step closer to one)*:

```
    def format_number(self, value, number_spec):
#        if number_spec[1] is None:
#            components = (value,)
#        else:
#            components = []
#            position = 0
#            last_index = len(number_spec) - 1
#            for index, chunk in enumerate(number_spec[1]):
#                if index == last_index:
#                    components.append(value[position:])
#                else:
#                    components.append(value[position:position+chunk])
#                    position += chunk
#        return ' '.join(components)
        return value
```

Debugging it is going to be hard because I have know idea what it does. *(Trust me I'm really trying!! I'm just new to this whole python stuff)*

Comment: No, no-one can help you track down the problem if you don't provide any code.

Comment: I have added some debugging directions, but if you're still having problems, can you chuck the whole file which has that in it, along with your usage of it, in a pastebin for us and let us know how you call it? Then I'll have a look through it. my suspicion is that there's a problem with your number format.

Comment: I tried your code again below and I got `020 8111 2222`?!? I tried django again and the `number_spec` came out as `3,4,4` which is the way it should be formatting it. I'll paste bin when I get time, but I'm not using it in any weird way, I've just defined the following in one of my forms `number = UKPhoneNumberField()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks likes its caused by the following in format_number

```
last_index = len(number_spec) - 1
```

As the code loops the second (or last -1) iteration will match, this results in the code appending 81112222 (position:) to the string rather then 8111, the 3rd iteration then adds 8111. Removing - 1 form the code solves this however I'm guessing this will affect the field in others ways.

Comment: For reference, this line should say `last_index = len(number_spec[1]) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You may not be good as debugging python, but this is your chance to learn. Try stepping through it with pdb (it's fairly well documented). If you can give a code-snippet including your model definition and the code adding that number to your db, I'll see if I can give you a hand.

Manual debugging is a skill you're going to need to develop if you want to get very far with these sorts of problems.

I tried:

```
def format_number(value, number_spec):
    components = []
    position = 0
    last_index = len(number_spec) - 1
    for index, chunk in enumerate(number_spec):
        if index == last_index:
            components.append(value[position:])
        else:
            components.append(value[position:position+chunk])
            position += chunk
    print components
print format_number('02081112222', (3, 4, 4))
```

obviously I've tweaked it to not need the rest of the code, but this seems to be working fine...

Comment: Hummm. I tried it without that code in the class/function and it worked fine. We must be looking at different results

Comment: @Sevenearths ok, add `import pdb`at the top of that file, then `pdb.settrace()` as the first line in that function.When you reach that point in execution it'll stop and you can type the name of any variable to examine its content; `b #` where # is a line number to set another breakpoint, `s` to step into a function, `n` to go to the next line, `c` to skip to the next breakpoint and `out` to step to the next return statement(or the last line before you return if implicit). At some point something is not doing what it should be. this should make it glaringly obvious. Welcome to debugging :)